# Import module within a class

Tags: python, class, import

I'd like to make a class that stores all my database connection information. So when I'm writing an ad-hoc analysis, all I would do is import my class and I would have all my connection readily available. It's my first time using classes but here is what I've tried but it's giving me a missing self argument.

[image]

Comment: Typically you import at the top of the file, not within a class. And I'm not sure why you think you want `__import__`

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? "missing self argument" is more than a bit vague.

Comment: You posted a picture of your code which means we can't copy/paste to try it out. You should post the actual code if you want more help.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "can't reproduce". Nothing seems wrong on visual inspection and OP isn't posting any more details.

Comment: Using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: As cricket hinted, use `import sqlalchemy` instead of the function call.